# How to restrict channels to publish to on Azure Cache for Redis PubSub?

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to restrict the ability to publish to specific channels on Redis PubSub. I saw that Redis uses glob style pattern matching, however, there do not seem to be any examples of how to implement this or if the pattern matching supports negation. Could someone provide an example?

[https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/#acl-rules:~:text=%26%3Cpattern%3E%3A%20](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/#acl-rules:%7E:text=%26%3Cpattern%3E%3A%20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Cache for Redis runs on version 6.0 and this feature becomes available in Redis 6.2, so is impossible to do within Azure Cache for Redis currently. ACR is supposedly upgrading to Redis 7.0 later in 2023